# Including a plugin with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to get the angularjs [grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) to work with row drag and drop support.  But it looks like they have pulled that functionality out into a [plugin](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/plugins/ng-grid-reorderable.js), and not updated their documentation at all.  That just looks like a function to me... how do I include this functionality with the grid in my app?  I already have the grid working and included:

```
var app = angular.module('webtools', ['$strap.directives', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngGrid']);
```

Comment: Ensure you to have loaded the ngGrid plugin dependencies. Maybe isolate it in a jsFiddle or something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller just add the following

```
var plugin = new ngSomePlugin();

$scope.gridOptions = {
    plugins: [plugin],
};
```